# Powershell capture first filename from a folder

Tags: powershell

Newbie to powershell
I need to capture first file name from a directory. However my current script captures all file names. Please suggest changes to my code below.

```
#   Storing path of the desired folder
$path = "C:\foo\bar\"
$contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse
$contents.Name
```

The result is following

```
test-01.eof
test-02.eof
test-03.eof
```

i just want one file (any) from this list. So expected result should be

```
test-01.eof
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use Select-Object with the -first switch and set it to 1

```
$path = "C:\foo\bar\"
$contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse -File | Select-Object -First 1
```

I've added the -File switch to `Get-ChildItem` as well, since you only want to return files.

Answer (score 7):

```
$path = "C:\foo\bar\"
$contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse
$contents # lists out all details of all files
$contents.Name # lists out all files
$contents[0].Name # will return 1st file name
$contents[1].Name # will return 2nd file name
$contents[2].Name # will return 3rd file name
```

The count starts from 0. So `$contents` here is an array or a list and whatever integer you mention in `[]` is the position of the item in that array/list. So when you type `$contents[9]`, you are telling powershell that get the 9th item from the array `$contents`. This is how you iterate through a list. In most programming languages the count begins from 0 and not 1. It is a bit confusing for a someone who is entering the coding world but you get used to it.

Comment: It surely would be helpfull for users new to powershell if you would explain your answer a little bit more detailed ;)

Answer (score 2):

Please use below command which is simple and helpful. Adding recurse will only put slight load on the machine or powershell (when the code is huge and it has been used somewhere)

## Storing path of the desired folder

```
$path = "C:\foo\bar\"
$contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | sort | Select-Object -First 1
$contents.Name
```

## Output Will be as as expected:

```
test-01.eof
```

Select-Object -First  will select each object (or row) and provide first row data as an output if you put  as 1

Comment: Just do `$fileName = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path | sort | Select-Object -First 1).Name`